# How can I show that $u=e^{\sigma\sqrt{\Delta t}}$ in the binomial option pricing model

Tags: taylor-expansion, finance

Given that

$e^{r\Delta t}(u+d)-ud-e^{2r\Delta t} = \sigma^2\Delta t$

I would like to show that

$u=e^{\sigma\sqrt{\Delta t}}$

I know I must somehow use Taylor's approximation $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}+...$ and ignore terms of $\Delta t$ higher than 1, but I can't seem to get to the value of $u$. Can someone show me this derivation?

Comment: can you explain your notations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that $ud=1$(Pretty standard approach)
We find that 
$$
u^2 -Ru +1 =0
$$
Where 
$$
R = \mathrm{e}^{-r\Delta t}+\mathrm{e}^{r\Delta t}+\sigma^2\Delta t \mathrm{e}^{-r\Delta t}
$$
We know we can't taylor expand now since the volatility will disappear straight away!

So solutions to the quadratic for $u$ is
$$
u =\frac{R\pm\sqrt{R^2 -4}}{2}
$$
Inserting $R$ back in we find
$$
u =\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-r\Delta t}+\mathrm{e}^{r\Delta t}+\sigma^2\Delta t \mathrm{e}^{-r\Delta t}\pm \sqrt{ \mathrm{e}^{-2r\Delta t} +  \mathrm{e}^{2r\Delta t} +2 + \sigma^4(\Delta t )^2 \mathrm{e}^{-2r\Delta t} +2\sigma^2\Delta t \left( \mathrm{e}^{-2r\Delta t} + 1\right) -4}}{2}
$$
After that rather ugly expression we can taylor expand and under the root we ignore $(\Delta t)^2$ terms and outside $\Delta t$ terms.

So we end up having
$$
u =\frac{2 + \sqrt{4+4\sigma^2\Delta t -4}}{2} = 1 + \pm\sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}
$$
Since we are looking at the up and we require $\sigma \geq 0$ and $ud =1$ it is obvious we must take the positive sign. Thus
$$
u = 1 + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}\approx \mathrm{e}^{\sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}}
$$